# How to include special characters like "-" in a resource path of a ballerina service

Tags: resources, ballerina

My requirement is to create an endpoint for `/school/{student-id}`.
I tried the below code.

```ballerina
service /school on new http:Listener(9000) {
    resource function get student/[string student\-id]() returns Student? {
        return studentTable[student\-id];
    }
}

public type Student record {|
    readonly string student\-id;
    string name;
    int age;
|};

public final table<Student> key(student\-id) studentTable = table [
    {student\-id: "333X", name: "Ross", age: 15},
    {student\-id: "465Q", name: "Kyle", age: 16}
];
```

I am getting `error: service registration failed: Invalid character: '\' in expression` for the above code.

How can I get the `student-id` to work as the resource path parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the code written above is correct. The error is due to a bug in older versions of ballerina. However, the bug seem to be fixed for versions above `ballerina swan-lake 2201.6.0`

There's another way you can include special characters. Here `002D` is the unicode code point for `-`. This works with the versions below `2201.6.0` as well.
e.g.

```ballerina
resource function get student/[string student\u{002D}id]() returns Student? { }
```

In a nutshell, you can use either backslash(`\`) or unicode numeric escape(`\u{xxxx}`) to include special characters in the resource path or any identifier defined in ballerina.

Sample endpoint implementations:

1. GET `/school/{student-id}`

```ballerina
service /school on new http:Listener(9000) {
    resource function get student/[string student\-id]() returns Student? {
        // logic goes here
    }
}
```

or

```ballerina
service /school on new http:Listener(9000) {
    resource function get student/[string student\u{002D}id]() returns Student? {
        // logic goes here
    }
}
```

2. GET `/school/student-performance`

```ballerina
service /school on new http:Listener(9000) {
    resource function get student\-performance() returns StPerformance[] {
        // logic goes here
    }
}
```

or

```ballerina
service /school on new http:Listener(9000) {
    resource function get student\u{002D}performance() returns StPerformance[] {
        // logic goes here
    }
}
```